# Can someone please fix the link in the 'access to moderator tools' privilege page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center

I was discussing deletion privileges with someone when I noticed that [help/privileges/moderator-tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) includes an unformatted link:

[image: image of part of help/privileges/moderator-tools showing the unformatted link]

Can the page be updated so the link reads as the actual title of the post, instead of the unformatted full link?